# Como rotear páginas no Electron?

Tags: electron, rotas

Tenho uma aplicação no Electron com vários arquivos HTML e eu gostaria de criar rotas no Electron assim como no Express. Por exemplo, na página inicial da aplicação o usuário deverá realizar um login, como no código abaixo:

```html
<form action="login.html" method="get">
    <input class="data_field" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input class="data_field" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Nesse código acima, o aplicativo redireciona diretamente para a outra página HTML onde será feita as validações e outros, mas não é isso o que eu quero.

Eu quero enviar o formulário através de uma rota que não é esse arquivo HTML, e com puro JS quero capturar a requisição, validar as informações e só depois disso, devolver um novo arquivo HTML como se fosse um servidor. Como posso fazer esse tipo de coisa no Electron?

```js
// Um código de exemplo do que eu quero fazer no Electron
electron.post("/login", (request, response) => {
    const username = request.body.username;
    const password = request.body.password;
    
    if (database[username] && database[username].password === password) {
        response.sendFile("myHTMLFile.html");
    } else {
        response.sendFile("otherFile.html");
    }
});
```

```html
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <input class="data_field" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input class="data_field" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Você ta fazendo o login local?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161836/nodejs-electron-with-express

Comment: @AnittaDeveloper sim o login é feito localmente. Eu gostaria apenas de tratar as requisições com JS puro, sem precisar redirecionar para um arquivo HTML como eu mostrei no primeiro exemplo na pergunta.

Comment: Você precisa usa o express ou um html que acesse a database